# How to open gallery from link?

Tags: html, css

Not sure what is relevant or how deep to explain.  I found a nice working gallery from **"magnific-popups"**.

I can get everything to work, but the user must click on a graphic within the gallery `div` to open the gallery.

I'm wanting the link from a different `div` to open the gallery but I can't include the gallery `div` `body` in the `div` that includes the link.

I thought of using `onclick` to refer to a **js** function that resides on my **script.js** but I can't get that to work and I'm not sure it's it the correct line to take.

I also thought of setting the `href` on my link to an `id` of one of the gallery photo's so clicking the link might open a gallery picture and cause the gallery to open.

Couldn't get that work.

I'd paste some code but I don't know if my question is intelligible (or hopefully simple to answer!)

**edit** *(added code)*

Not sure how to format.  This is my index.html.  I want menu to pop up the gallery but the best I can get is an icon to pop a gallery up from the first div below:

```
   <nav>
            <div class="row">
                <img src="Resources/img/Pizza_Pi_Logo_Trans.gif" alt="Pizza Pi logo" class="logo">
                <img src="Resources/img/Pizza_Pi_Logo_Trans.gif" alt="Pizza Pi logo" class="logo-black">

                <div class="popup-gallery">
                        <a href="Resources/img/Pizza_Pi_Menu.png" title="The Cleaner"><img src="Resources/img/Pizza_Pi_Menu.png" width="75" height="75"></a>
                        <a href="Resources/img/Pizza_Pi_Menu2.png" title="The Cleaner"></a>
                    </div>

                <ul class="main-nav js--main-nav">

                    <li><a href="#features">HOME</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#cities">PIZZAS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#plans">SPECIALS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#form">CONTACT</a></li> 
                    <li><a href="#">MENU</a></li>
                </ul>
             <a class="mobile-nav-icon js--nav-icon"><i class="ion-navicon-round"></i></a>

            </div>     
            </nav>
```

The script.js file has this:

```
$('.popup-gallery').magnificPopup({
        delegate: 'a',
        type: 'image',
        tLoading: 'Loading image #%curr%...',
        mainClass: 'mfp-img-mobile',
        gallery: {
            enabled: true,
            navigateByImgClick: true,
            preload: [0,1] // Will preload 0 - before current, and 1 after the current image
        },
        image: {
            tError: '<a href="%url%">The image #%curr%</a> could not be loaded.',
            titleSrc: function(item) {
                return item.el.attr('title') + '<small>by Marsel Van Oosten</small>';
            }
        }
    });
```

Edit 3: I would like the menu link to pop up the gallery, but if i put the 
div class="popup-gallery" around the menu link it runs the list/navi display.

Comment: I can help you if you add the code

Comment: Added what I think is relevant, thanks for the help!

Comment: On, what exactly needs to be clicked, to pop the gallery? for you

Comment: I would like the menu link to pop up the gallery, but if i put the <div class="popup-gallery"> around the menu link it runs the list/navi display.

Comment: try using `<ul class="main-nav js--main-nav popup-gallery">` this. I mean replace it with current ul class

Comment: I think what happens is then the gallery expects a picture from every link.  Then the gallery has 7 pictures 2 that I want and 5 that are empty.  It tries to take a picture from every link.

I think that is the:

     delegate: 'a',

Comment: Ok, wait, 
you mean when anyone clicks inside `<ul class="main-nav js--main-nav">`
you want `<div class="popup-gallery">` to work?

Comment: Only when they click menu.  When they click menu I would like the 2 menu pictures to pop up in a gallery.  If I put popup-gallery in the <ul class="main-nav js--main-nav"> then the gallery tries to fill with pictures from each link which I think is not useful.

Comment: Can you link your site?

Comment: http://www.pizzapi.ca/

Comment: I woke up in the morning and had an idea in my head!  It didn't work at all!  But then I created a pop-gallery class for the li element and a separate div that holds the gallery pics


Seems to work great

Answer (score 0):

```
                    <li><a href="#features">HOME</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#cities">PIZZAS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#plans">SPECIALS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#Resources/img/Pizza_Pi_Menu.png">CONTACT</a></li>
                    <li class="popup-gallery"><a href="Resources/img/Pizza_Pi_Menu.png" Title="Menu">MENU</a></li></ul>
             <a class="mobile-nav-icon js--nav-icon"><i class="ion-navicon-round"></i></a>

            </div>     


        </nav>

        <div class="popup-gallery">
                <a href="Resources/img/Pizza_Pi_Menu2.png" title="Menu 2"></a>
        </div>
```

Comment: A little explanation would be helpful. What is your solution and how does it solve the problem?

Comment: When I click menu menu.png opens and the class "popup-gallery" causes the js code for a gallery to fire.  The gallery loads menu.png and then whats in the div with the "popup-gallery" thus creating a 2 picture menu.